# The derived category is additive

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories, derived-categories

Let $\mathcal C$ be an abelian category. One way to see the derived category $D(\mathcal C)$ is that it has

- the same objects as $\operatorname{Ch}(\mathcal C)$,
- roofs $A\xleftarrow{\simeq}Z_1\rightarrow Z_2\xleftarrow{\simeq}Z_3\rightarrow\cdots \xleftarrow{\simeq}Z_n\rightarrow B$ as morphisms.

To see that $D(\mathcal C)$ is additive, it suffices to show that it contains finite biproducts, for then we can define the addition of morphisms in terms of $\oplus$. So the goal is to find a biproduct of two objects $A, B\in D(\mathcal C)$.

Clearly, for the object $A\oplus B$ from $\operatorname{Ch}(\mathcal C)$ there are inclusion morphisms $A\to A\oplus B\leftarrow B$. Let $T$ be an object with morphisms

$$A\xleftarrow{\simeq}C_1\rightarrow T,\quad
 B\xleftarrow{\simeq}C_2\rightarrow T.$$

Note that it suffices to consider single-step roofs because the argument, once established, can be iterated for general roofs as above.

We see that there is a morphism $A\oplus B\xleftarrow{\simeq} C_1\oplus C_2\to T$, making the diagram commute. However, I fail to show its uniqueness: Given another morphism $A\oplus B\xleftarrow{\simeq} Z\to T$, we have to show that both are equivalent, i.e., there is an object $Y$ with morphisms such that

$$\begin{matrix}
&&Z\\
&\swarrow&\uparrow&\searrow\\
A&\leftarrow &Y&\rightarrow &T\\
&\nwarrow&\downarrow&\nearrow\\
&& C_1\oplus C_2
\end{matrix}$$

commutes, where $Y\xrightarrow{\simeq} A$.

**Question:** How to I find this object $Y$, showing uniqueness of the canonical morphism from $A\oplus B$ to $T$?

Comment: the localization of an additive category is additive category.Thus you only need to check homotopy category is additive category.

Comment: @Sky That $K(\mathcal C)$ is additive is clear. However, it is not totally clear to me that the localisation of an additive category yields an additive one again.

Comment: How do you define the sum of two morphisms $f, g: A \rightrightarrows B$ using biproducts? You have a map $(f, g): A \to B \oplus B$, but to obtain a sum, you need some addition map $+: B \oplus B \to B$?

Comment: @red_trumpet Use $A\to A\oplus A\to B\oplus B\to B$, where $B\oplus B\to B$ is obtained from the universal property of the coproduct, and $A\to A\oplus A$ from the u.p. of the product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, hom sets of the derived category is easily endowed with the structure of abelian groups.

- For addition, consider two roofs $X\xleftarrow[\simeq]{q_1}Z_1\xrightarrow{f_1} Y$ and $X\xleftarrow[\simeq]{q_2}Z_2\xrightarrow{f_2} Y$. The Ore condition for a multiplicative system (which quasi-isomorphisms are an instance of) ensures that there is an object $Z$ and a qis $q$ such that
  $$\begin{matrix}
  Z&\xrightarrow[\simeq]{p_1}&Z_1\\
  \llap{\scriptstyle p_2}\downarrow&&\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle q_1}\\
  Z_2&\xrightarrow[q_2]{\simeq}&X
  \end{matrix}$$
  commutes. Since $q_1$ also is a qis, the two-of-three property implies that $p_2$ also is a qis. Let $q=q_1p_1=q_2p_2$. We have brought $f_1q_1^{-1}=(f_1p_1)q^{-1}$ and $f_2q_2^{-1}=(f_2p_2)q^{-1}$ to a common denominator, such that we can simply write $$f_1q_1^{-1} + f_2q_2^{-1}=(f_1p_1 + f_2p_2)q^{-1},$$ where addition now takes place in the category $\operatorname{Ch}(\mathcal C)$.
- Additive inverses are immediately constructed: $-fq^{-1}=(-1f)q^{-1}$.

However, he original question was why the localisation has biproducts; in particular, why the universal morphism is unique. This can also be seen using the Ore condition. We just care for coproducts; the proof for products is dual.

Consider roofs $X\xleftarrow[\simeq]{q_1}Z_1\xrightarrow{f_1} T$ and $X\xleftarrow[\simeq]{q_2}Z_2\xrightarrow{f_2} T$ as above.

- There is a unique morphism $X\oplus Y \xleftarrow[\simeq]{(q_1, q_2)} Z_1\oplus Z_2\xrightarrow{(f_1, f_2)} T$. The two morphisms exist by the universal property of $Z_1\oplus Z_2$, and $(q_1, q_2)$ is a qis since direct sums preserve qis.
- The morphism $X\oplus Y\leftarrow\bullet\to T$ is unique: Let $X\oplus Y\xleftarrow[\simeq]{p}C\xrightarrow{g} T$ be another morphism such that
  $$\begin{matrix}
  X & \rightarrow &X\oplus Y&\leftarrow& Y\\
  \uparrow && \uparrow && \uparrow\\
  Z_1 && C && Z_2\\
  & \searrow &\downarrow &\swarrow\\
  && T
  \end{matrix}\label{diag1}\tag{*}$$
  commutes in the derived category. By the Ore condition, we can find $C_1$, $C_2$ and morphisms such that
  $$\begin{matrix}
  C_1 & \xrightarrow{f_1} & C\\
  \llap{\scriptstyle p_1}\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\simeq} && \llap{\scriptstyle p}\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\simeq}\\
  X & \rightarrow & X\oplus Y
  \end{matrix},
  \qquad
  \begin{matrix}
  C_2 & \xrightarrow{f_2} & C\\
  \llap{\scriptstyle p_2}\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\simeq} && \llap{\scriptstyle p}\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\simeq}\\
  Y & \rightarrow & X\oplus Y
  \end{matrix}\label{diag2}\tag{**}$$
  commutes. Since $C_1\oplus C_2\xrightarrow{\simeq}X\oplus Y$, the 2-of-3 property imples that $C\to C_1\oplus C_2$ is a qis.
  Commutativity of \eqref{diag1} means that there are objects $B_1$, $B_2$ such that
  $$\begin{matrix}
  &&X&&\longrightarrow&&X\oplus Y &&\longleftarrow && Y \\
  &\llap{\scriptstyle\simeq}\nearrow&\llap{\scriptstyle\simeq}\uparrow&\nwarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\simeq}&&&\llap{\scriptstyle\simeq}\uparrow&&&\llap{\scriptstyle\simeq}\nearrow&\llap{\scriptstyle\simeq}\uparrow&\nwarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\simeq}\\
  Z_1&\xleftarrow[]{\simeq}&B_1&\xrightarrow{\simeq}&C_1 & \leftarrow & C & \rightarrow & C_2&\xleftarrow[]{\simeq}&B_2&\xrightarrow{\simeq}&Z_2\\
  &\searrow&\downarrow&\swarrow&&&\downarrow&&&\searrow&\downarrow&\swarrow\\
  &&T&&=&&T&&=&&T
  \end{matrix}
  $$
  commutes.
  Finally, $B_1\oplus B_2\xrightarrow{\simeq}Z_1\oplus Z_2$, but also $B_1\oplus B_2\xrightarrow{\simeq} C_1\oplus C_2\xleftarrow{\simeq} C$, where the last qis was explained after \eqref{diag2}, and the entire diagram commutes.

The object $B_1\oplus B_2$ thus is the one rendering $X\xleftarrow{\simeq} Z_1\oplus Z_2\rightarrow Y$ and $X\xleftarrow{\simeq} C\rightarrow Y$ equivalent, and we have shown that the universal morphism out of $X\oplus Y$ is unique.

Comment: I'm having some trouble showing that this definition of addition in the hom-sets is well defined. The first thing we do is choose two roofs that represent two morphisms in the derived category and then with these representatives we define the sum. What if we start with two different roofs representing the same morphisms?